# Chern classes of the sheaf of LOG differentials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, chern-classes

Let $\Omega_X^1(\log D)$ be the (locally free) of logarithmic differentials on a smooth projective variety $X$ with respect to a simple normal crossing divisor $D$.

What are the Chern classes of $\Omega_X^1(\log D)$ in terms of the Chern classes of $\Omega_X^1$ and $D$? 
I think, the first one is 
$$c_1(\Omega_X^1(\log D))= c_1(\Omega_X^1)+D.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $D_1,\ldots,D_m$ be the irreducible components of $D$. The reasoning in Prp 2.3 in MR1240599 gives an exact sequence
$$0\longrightarrow \Omega_X^1\longrightarrow \Omega_X^1(\log D)\longrightarrow\bigoplus_{i=1}^m{\mathcal O}_{D_i}\longrightarrow 0.$$
Thus, the total Chern class is given by
$$c\big(\Omega_X^1(\log D)\big)=c(\Omega_X^1)\Big/\prod_{i=1}^m\big(1-[D_i]\big).$$
Mohammad's formula for the first Chern class is correct.

Answer (score 8):

From the exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow \Omega ^1_X\rightarrow \Omega ^1_X(\log D)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_D\rightarrow 0$$you get $\ c(\Omega ^1_X(\log D))=c(\Omega ^1_X).c(\mathcal{O}_D)=c(\Omega ^1_X).(1-[D])^{-1}$, hence
$$c_p(\Omega ^1_X(\log D))=c_p(\Omega ^1_X)+c_{p-1}(\Omega ^1_X).[D]+\ldots +[D]^p\ .$$

Comment: I think this is correct only if D is smooth. Take a look at Prp 2.3/2.4 in MR1240599. Both formulas there extend to arbitrary simple normal crossings divisors.